# How to program your Arduino Due while its connected to a display?

Tags: shields, arduino-due

Im trying to program my Arduino Due and it seems that I have to disconnect the display from it every time. Is there a work around for this?

Im using a 7" TFT with a CTE TFT LCD/SD Shield with a arduino due board.

Comment: Which arduino pins are wired up to the display?

Comment: You need to connect the ChipSelect/Enable pin connected to the Arduino, not just tied to ground